# Identity Server 4 extending auth session

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, okta

I have been struggling with this for several weeks, now, and I simply cannot find the answer.

I have set up Identity Server 4 as a go-between for Okta as an ID provider for a couple of Angular applications. It works pretty darned well for that purpose. Except that, no matter what I try to change, after 30 minutes, silent refreshes report "login required". And search Google as I might, I simply cannot seem to figure out how to keep that session alive. Or I'm possibly blind, and am missing it. It seems a simple thing - extend a session - but somewhere I'm hitting a roadblock and am unable to do so.

My Setup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OpenID Connect", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.UseTokenLifetime = true;

    options.Authority = Configuration["Authority"];
    options.ClientId = Configuration["OktaAppId"];
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        RoleClaimType = "role", SaveSigninToken = true
    };
});
```

This SO question appears related, but it's from 2017 and has no apparent resolution, either: [Session Timeout when using IdentityServer4 and Oidc client causing Silent Renew to stop working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969638/session-timeout-when-using-identityserver4-and-oidc-client-causing-silent-renew)

My silent refresh code is working - I'm getting new tokens with each call. But after 30 minutes the call to the authorization endpoint winds up killing the idsrv.session cookie, which appears to be the authorization session cookie. Resolutions that I've found for extending sessions appear related to logins that do not utilize OIDC, and thus it seems that the session extensions do not apply to my situation (at the very least, the properties that need to be changed do not exist on the OIDC options object).

Another curious, and perhaps relevant, detail... It appears that when the authorize endpoint is hit, with prompt=none for the silent refresh, there is no redirect to Okta. I'm not sure if this is significant, or if ID4 is supposed to be communicating directly with OKta to verify its session.

At any rate, I'm at my wit's end. I usually do not post questions to SO because I seem to be pretty terrible at writing quality questions. Hopefully I've covered the needs for the community with this one, though.